# Is there a better way to write this string interpolation?

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I have to write a beautiful piece of code but I am not happy with the following syntax.

Is there a better way to write this string interpolation?

```
var details = $"{((currentProfile.FirstName != newProfile.FirstName) ? $"{Environment.NewLine}First Name : {newProfile.FirstName}" : string.Empty)}" +
    $"{((currentProfile.LastName != newProfile.LastName) ? $"{Environment.NewLine}Last Name : {newProfile.LastName}" : string.Empty)}" +
    $"{((currentProfile.MiddleName != newProfile.MiddleName) ? $"{Environment.NewLine}Middle Name : {newProfile.MiddleName}" : string.Empty)}" +
    $"{((currentProfile.Suffix != newProfile.Suffix) ? $"{Environment.NewLine}Suffix : {newProfile.Suffix}" : string.Empty)}" +
    $"{((currentProfile.AddressLine1 != newProfile.AddressLine1) ? $"{Environment.NewLine}Address Line 1 : {newProfile.AddressLine1}" : string.Empty)}" +
    $"{((currentProfile.AddressLine2 != newProfile.AddressLine2) ? $"{Environment.NewLine}Address Line 2 : {newProfile.AddressLine2}" : string.Empty)}" +
    $"{((currentProfile.City != newProfile.City) ? $"{Environment.NewLine}City : {newProfile.City}" : string.Empty)}"+
    $"{((currentProfile.ProvinceCode != newProfile.ProvinceCode) ? $"{Environment.NewLine}State : {newProfile.ProvinceCode}" : string.Empty)}" +
    $"{((currentProfile.ZipCode != newProfile.ZipCode) ? $"{Environment.NewLine}Zip Code : {newProfile.ZipCode}" : string.Empty)}" + 
    $"{((currentProfile.CountryCode != newProfile.CountryCode) ? $"{Environment.NewLine}Country : {newProfile.CountryCode}" : string.Empty)}" +
    $"{((currentProfile.Phone != newProfile.Phone) ? $"{Environment.NewLine}Phone : {newProfile.Phone}" : string.Empty)}";
```

Comment: Use `if` or a custom method, it's much clearer in this case and allows to set breakpoints everywhere

Comment: Use array of strings like `FirstName`, `LastName`. Them process all this with loop.

Comment: @i486 if you loop in the way you describe, you'll be using reflection - that's adding overhead *and* complexity without any particular gain... but maybe I'm misunderstanding you (would be easier to tell with a code answer)

Comment: I don't think i486's solution would require reflection, just a mapping of key-values (label and value). @MarcGravell

Comment: @PatrickHofman that seems to be a lot of unnecessary complexity to add to a simple operation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

personally I'd probably use something like:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
AppendIfDifferent(sb, currentProfile.FirstName, newProfile.FirstName, "First Name");
AppendIfDifferent(sb, currentProfile.LastName, newProfile.LastName, "Last Name");
// ...
string s = sb.ToString();
```

with:

```
static void AppendIfDifferent(StringBuilder sb, string newValue,
        string oldValue, string label)
{
    if(newValue != oldValue)
    {
        sb.AppendLine().Append(label).Append(" : ").Append(newValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify a lot by making an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string IfNotEquals(this string s1, s2, string label)
    {
        if (s1 != s2)
        {
            return label + s1;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Which you would use like this:

```
$"{currentProfile.LastName.IfNotEquals(newProfile.LastName, "Last name:")}"
```